# Remove last directory in nginx proxy url

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

How i can rewrite proxy url in nginx? Example:

```
example.com/s/imageName/someString.png
```

to

```
localhost:2228/foo/bar/imageName.png
```

Naturally using nginx proxy

Comment: You can use a [`rewrite...break`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) within the `location` block containing the `proxy_pass` statement.

Comment: @RichardSmith i know but what regex in rewrite?

Comment: Something like this: `^/s/([^/]+)/[^/]+\.(png|jpg|gif)$ /foo/bar/$1.$2`

Comment: @RichardSmith can you give all nginx config?